# Extensions of the BCFW recursion relations

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-chromodynamics, gluons

In their "original" form the BCFW recursion relations are used to calculate tree-level (color-ordered) $n$-gluon amplitudes. However is it possible to extend this formalism to more general QCD amplitudes (that involve e.g. massive or massless fermions) or QED amplitudes?